# Visualizing K8S CPU resources Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I'm new with monitoring tools like Prometheus and Grafana and I would like to create dashboard which represents current `requests and limits resources` and usage for a pod. In addition, this pod has 2 containers inside.

My resources for first container looks like:

```
 resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "3800m"
      memory: "9500Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "6500m"
      memory: "9500Mi"
```

and for second container:

```
resources:
   limits:
     cpu: 100m
     memory: 100Mi
   requests:
     cpu: 50m
     memory: 50Mi
```

When executing this query in Prometheus:

`rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"MY_POD"}[5m])`
I get: [image]
And to be honest I dont know how this returned data are valid with resources. On Grafana it looks like this:
[image]

In addition I would like to add informations about `requests and limits` to dashboard, but I don't know how to scale dashboard to show all data.

When I execute this query: `kube_pod_container_resource_requests{pod=~"MY_POD"}` I get:

[image]

And this looks valid compared to my resources. I have proper value for limits too, but I would like to represent all this data (usage, requests, limits) on ona dashboard. Could somebody give my any tips how to achieve this?

Comment: you can use readymade dashboard, go do dashboard click import and use this id `6336`https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/6336-kubernetes-pods-prometheus/

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/6781-kubernetes-pod-overview/ this with id `6781`

Comment: @Adiii well this is really useful, just need to change parameters as `pod_name, container_name` are not supported in used version (`pod, container` is correct). I also have a question. For CPU Usage I got value `0.057`. Is this a percentage value or something different?

Comment: It should be percentages, you can click on and edit and see the formula if there is any percentage/100

Comment: @Adiii nope, just `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~"$namespace",pod=~"$pod",container=~"$container",container!="POD",image!=""}[2m]))`

Comment: So if summing value in the last two minutes, you can apply avg

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just add 2 more queries

> if you don't know where to add, below Metrics Browser and Options tab you
> can find + symbol to add more queries
>
> and `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` this metrics is a counter and
> this will give you the CPU Usage in Cores.

`kube_pod_container_resource_requests{pod=~"MY_POD"}` and `kube_pod_container_resource_limits{pod=~"MY_POD"}`. If it's only one Pod means no issues. But if you're having mutliple Pods means try to use `Sum`

- Query A: `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"MY_POD"}[5m]))`
- Query B: `sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{pod=~"MY_POD"})`
- Query C: `sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{pod=~"MY_POD"})`

This will looks good without too much details, for more details like container wise data just create three more Panel for Requests, Limits and Usage by Containers and add `by(container)` after the every Query

**Another Approach:**

Create Variables for Pod and Container so that you can select the Container which you want to see and add 3 queries in single panel so that the Panel looks more Dynamic and less Noise